# Disable Microsoft Edge rounded corners

Tags: microsoft-edge

I'm trying to remove the Microsoft Edge rounded corners feature (#edge-rounded-containers) in Experiments (edge://flags) for all my users on Windows 10/11.
It's also a toggle under Settings - Appearance, "Try the new look and feel of Microsoft Edge".

I need to find a way to run a script or something to patch Edge, but I can't seem to find any feasible solutions for that. Like, how do you script that? What's my best shot? Thank you so much!

Comment: Windows 11 has rounded corners and so too does Edge.  Windows 10 has square corners and so too does my Edge in my Windows 10 VM.  Since Windows 11 is on the horizon, best thing is to adapt to it.

Comment: Don’t get me wrong, I kinda dig the rounded edges of win11/edge. The problem with edge’s rounded corners is that it affects the way users see specific pages (too zoomed in even though it maintains the default 100% zoom). That’s why I need to deactivate it at least for some pages.

Comment: I have not seen this in normal Edge use.

Comment: I am just checking:   The rounding at the corners is really tiny. It does not affect any web page here. The rounding on Edge is the same as for all other WIndows 11 apps and windows.

Answer (score 2):

Navigate to `edge://flags/#edge-rounded-containers` in Edge. Toggle to disable.

Answer (score 0):

I have done a bit of research on this issue (rounded corners).

There is no way (in any research I have done) to change the rounded corners of Edge (browser), or for that matter the other Windows 11 apps.

> You said   "The problem with edge’s rounded corners is that it affects
> the way users see specific pages (too zoomed in even though it
> maintains the default 100% zoom)"

This seems a bit problematic.

I posted a screen shot of rounded corners (Edge and VMware in Windows 11) and square corners (Chrome in Kali) and the differences are only just perceptible.

Browsing in Edge is not affected that I can see.

So you and your users need to adapt to Edge specifically and other browsers in Windows 11.

If the particular web page is under your control, perhaps it should be changed.

[image: Rounded Corners]

Comment: Thank you for digging around! Yes, I mean if it wasn’t for a user reporting the issue I would never ever noticed the difference. Actually the problem arises with a specific Viva page on SharePoint, that happens to be the main landing page for the company. Some elements on the right side of the page get cut out and moved to the bottom of the central element.

Comment: Is there something wrong with your Edge App on Windows 10. I use Sharepoint and nothing is cut off. Works just fine.